# ifconfig does not recognize eth0, only wlan0 and lo (Ubuntu 14.04, Macbrook Pro)

Tags: networking, broadcom, ethernet

`ifconfig -a` produces:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1812 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1812 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:209274 (209.2 KB)  TX bytes:209274 (209.2 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:cf:e9:1a:43:cd  
          inet addr:192.168.12.11  Bcast:192.168.12.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2acf:e9ff:fe1a:43cd/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11512 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11320 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:9240182 (9.2 MB)  TX bytes:2316647 (2.3 MB)
```

`lspci -nn | grep Ethernet` produces:

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:16a3] (rev 10)
```

`cat /etc/network/interfaces` produces:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
```

Any ideas on how I can get eth0? Thanks!

Comment: Adding the lines `allow-hotplug eth0` and `iface eth0 inet dhcp` to the interfaces file should work, if you use DHCP and no network manager.

Comment: I added those 2 lines to the file and rebooted, but still dont see eth0. I think it has to do with the drivers, but I'm not sure.

Comment: After making the changes to the file (and saving) bring all interfaces down and eht0 up. To do that issue `ifdown wlan0` (will disconnect from the internet, use `ifup` to bring it back) `ifdown eth0` `ifup eth0`. Report back if it doesn't work. (Note all commands must be issued as root or with `sudo`, as well as making the changes to the interfaces file).

Comment: I saved those changes. When I do ifdown wlan0, I get the error - ifdown: interface wlan0 not configured.

Comment: That's expected, actually. I meant bring all interfaces you're connected to down. If you connected to wlan via a network-manager, disconnect from there. Then run the ifups and downs and see if it works... (ignore errors, just see if it connects to eth0)...

Comment: I disabled networking for the menubar on top. Then ran sudo ifup eth0. Got the error - Cannot find device "eth0" Error getting hardware address for "eth0": No such device Failed to bring up eth0.

Comment: and ifconfig still shows no eth0.

Comment: You are connected to an ethernet cable, right...?

Comment: noob question - do i need to be connected to an ethernet cable for eth0 to show up? (No i am not connected)

Comment: ifconfig (without `-a`) only shows the interfaces that are up. Usually, `eth0` is bring up even if you're not connected to an ethernet cable if you have `auto-hotplug eth0` (I didn't see your comment saying it still didn't show up on ifconfig). So it seems like a driver issue, yes. Remove the lines added to the interfaces file as you seem to be using a network manager (in my first comment I mentioned it should only be added if no network manager is being used).

Comment: Thanks - what drivers should I install? I removed bcmwl_kernel_source as wireless was not working with that. I installed firmware-b43-installer and b43-fwcutter.

Comment: I also installed linux-firmware-nonfree.

Answer (score 10):

Check whether your interface has the name `eth0` by typing `ifconfig -a`.

Probably it is named something like `p1p1` now. If it is and you want it to be `eth0`, add `biosdevname=0` to the boot options in your `/etc/default/grub`.

Comment: Alternatively you can just rename the interface from `eth0` to the assigned name in /etc/network/interfaces (`p1p1` in your example), assuming the correct configuration information has been added already for eth0 in that file.